# Rank and column/row space

Tags: matrix-rank

The question that I am trying to solve is

### Suppose that A is n × n and has rank n. What is its row space? What is its nullspace? What is its column space?

From rank nullity theorem, I know that the null space will be 0 because. Also, rank = dim(column space(A)) = dim(row space(A))

But the question asks for the row space and column space and not the dimensions of those. How can I find those two without knowing what the actual matrix is?
Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So you have a space $n$-vectors that has dimension $n$. What can that be?

Comment: Umm an identity matrix? I dont know what you are trying to get at. From what i know , since its a non singular matrix, it can be reduced to an identity matrix with no free variables.

Comment: Forget about the matrix, all the useful information is already distilled into the question as I asked it. Suppose you have three linearly independent vectors in 3-space. What do they span?

Comment: I think they span R^3. So by that logic the column and row space would be R^n?

Comment: Correct. Column space and null space are complementary (their sum is the whole space), the rank-nullity theorem tells you that the null space is $0$-dimensional, so it is just $\{0\}$. Its complement is the whole space.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still have one conceptual question. From the rank nullity theorem, we get to know that the dimension of row and column space is n. How does that imply that the 2 spaces span entire R^n. I know its probably a stupid question but I am trying to wrap my head around the difference between the dimension of a space and just the space itself. Thanks again

Comment: Because the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is also $n$. If you have $n$ vectors in it, and what they span has dimension $n$ they have no choice but to span it all. There are too many of them to span anything less. The [dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces) says all bases have the same number of elements. Anything less than  $\mathbb{R}^n$ must have lower dimension, so it can not contain $n$ independent vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If $T: V\to V$, and the rank equals $n$, the dimension of $V$, then the range, column space, and row space are necessarily $V$.